# Getting the company name for permission settings Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

We are currently integrating google drive permissions into our app. We would like to be able to display the company name for permissions like google drive does currently. For example,
when you go to a file and select Share and change the share settings you are able to see the company name say "Acme, Co.".

Currently I am seeing that the permissions API returns domain, for example acmeco.com. Is there a way to retrieve the actual company name (Acme, Co.).

Thank you

Comment: Could maybe parse the URL, after all it's probably going to be the company name?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe that would work. For example United HealthCare Group may have uhg.org.blah... There would be no way of taking uhg.org and turning that into United HealthCare Group. Thanks though for the quick reply!